# Getting value from an abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

So I'm trying to get value of Speed from class Players and transfer it to variable newSpeed in Class Player1.However Iam still unable make Speed from Players pass the value to newSpeed of class Player1. The value of newspeed should have been 2 but it stil remains as 0. I have been stuck at it for more than 2 hours. I really need help.

P/S: I did not include my Driver class because i belive the problem lies somewhere here. However i can still include them here if u need it

Class Players:

```
    public abstract class Players {


   protected static int speed=2;
   private int x;
   private int y;
   public abstract void resetLocation();

   public int getSpeed()
   {
      return speed;
   }
}
```

Class Player 2

```
public class Player2 extends Players {

    private int newSpeed=1;

    Player2() {

        super.speed=this.newSpeed;
    }


    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return newSpeed;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Function to set how many steps can the player goes.
     */
    public void setMovementSpeed(int speed)
    {
        this.newSpeed=speed; //this is for another functionality.
    }

}
```

Main :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Player2 p2 = new Player2();


        System.out.println(p2.getSpeed());
    }
}
```

This is what i have tried.

Comment: your main method ? pls paste it

Comment: Why is `speed` static in class `Players` ? This should be an instance property.

Comment: Instance?. But aren't abstract class cannot instantiated

Comment: How did you run your probgram? I don't see public abstract void resetLocation(); method implementation.

Comment: It will print 1, what is the issue in this ?

Comment: Agree with @Kick, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is in the abstract class I have declared value of speed as 2. I need to pass that value into Player2 class which will set value newSpeed as 2. and the output should be 2

Comment: @slesh i removed it from here, but still have it in my program. Removed it from here because i thought it was necesary

Comment: Just replace this super.speed = this.newSpeed; with this.newSpeed; = super.speed

Comment: Works , Thanks @Slesh

Answer (score 0):

Change the Player2 as below to get expected result

```
Player2() {

        newSpeed = speed;
    }
```

In the Player2 Constructor you were setting the instance value to super instance value, so you have to change the condition to get expected result